# BAT FTP - отправка директорий

Tags: ftp, bat

Нужна помощь по использованию FTP в BAt. Возникла необходимость отправки по FTP директории.

```
put "D:/Директория/"
```

Знаю, что существует 3 команды для отправки файлов - `put`, `mput`, `send`. Однако, если я не ошибаюсь, ни одна из них не способна отправлять директории по FTP, знаю, что mput отправляет несколько файлов, но это совсем не то...

Ещё я не знаю, в какую сторону должны писаться слеши - **put "D:`/`Директория`/`"**. Заметил, что при выборе директории на сервере, куда необходимо загружать файлы, слеши пишутся вправо, а вот в какую сторону нужно писать здесь - вопрос...

Есть ли какое-нибудь решение вышеприведённой проблемы, или отправлять по FTP на сервер директории невозможно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> если я не ошибаюсь, ни одна из них не способна отправлять директории по FTP

Передача каталога с содержимым в принципе не предусмотрена FTP-протоколом. Если программа умеет это делать - то именно в ней программист реализовал необходимые операции по получению списка файлов и организации их передачи на FTP поштучно. Однако я не припоминаю CLI-программ с такой возможностью.

> не знаю, в какую сторону должны писаться слеши

В *nix - прямые, в Win - обратные (впрочем, в большинстве случаев и прямые допустимы, если нет опасности их перепутать с символом опции).

> Есть ли какое-нибудь решение вышеприведённой проблемы

Иногда на FTP-серверах стоЯт доп. расширения. Например, это может быть расширение, обрабатывающее команду "загрузить и разархивировать" (используется ZIP) - причём именно команду, а не фичу веб-морды. Если Ваш FTP имеет такого рода расширение - пользуйтесь. Хотя вероятность невелика.

> Возникла необходимость отправки по FTP директории.

Ну вообще не вижу большой проблемы организовать создание на сервере каталога и аплоада в него файлов. B BAT-файле выполняется получение листинга каталога и формирование из него командного файла для FTP-клиента, после чего клиент собственно и запускается.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, я так и думал. Однако, недавно нашел код - [сам код >](http://brnk.cf/code.txt). Основная его проблема - либо он копирует то, что находится в каталоге, в котором находится сам батник, либо копирует только то, что находится в корне диска (к примеру, необходимо скопировать D:\Папка\Папка с файлами\, а он копирует только файлы, находящиеся в корне диска D:\). Помогите с ним разобраться, надеюсь, в TXT вам удобно будет смотреть код. В комментарии не влазит!(

Comment: И ещё: я заметил, что не отправляются картинки (*.jpg, *.jpeg, *.png ...). Нужно ли писать команду `binary` и как это сделать в вышеупомянутом коде ([сам код >](http://brnk.cf/code.txt))? Использовал его, подставлял перед маской файлов, но увы, команда не распознавалась.

Comment: _подставлял перед маской файлов_ - а надо в коде формирования командного файла (вероятно, перед строкой `echo mput %mask%`).

Comment: Ясно, спасибо!)